# SOLR Parser for Abbreviated words with periods

Tags: solr

IN SOLR Apache 3.6 when doing a search for USC with highlights selected, why does it not also pick up U.S.C. as well in the highlighted results?

The field type is the following:

```
 <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
   <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I want SOLR to return U.S.C. as well as USC in the highlighted search results.

However it's returning just USC:

```
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">7</int><lst name="params"><str name="explainOther"/><str name="fl">*,score</str><str name="indent">on</str><str name="start">0</str><str name="q">USC</str><str name="hl.fl">*</str><str name="wt"/><str name="fq"/><str name="hl">on</str><str name="version">2.2</str><str name="rows">10</str></lst></lst><result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="0.047945753"><doc><float name="score">0.047945753</float><str name="id">978-064172344522</str><arr name="title"><str>my <a href="www.foo.bar">link</a>  power-shot PowerShot USC Utility <br>hello</br> Rejections Under 35 U.S.C. 101 and 35 U.S.C. 112, First Paragraph Petitions to correct inventorship of an issued patent are decided by the <Underline>Supervisory Patent Examiner</Underline>, as set forth</str></arr></doc></result><lst name="highlighting"><lst name="978-064172344522"><arr name="title"><str>my <a href="www.foo.bar">link</a>  power-shot PowerShot <em>USC</em> Utility <br>hello</br> Rejections Under</str></arr></lst></lst></response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the analysis page in Solr, and run the string "U.S.C." on a fieldType of `text_en_splitting` you will see that it gets indexed as three separate tokens: `u`, `s`, and `c`. Play around with the attributes of the WordDelimiterFilterFactory (perhaps the catenateAll attribute) and see if you can get it to index as `usc` (one token) instead of three split up tokens. If that doesn't work, maybe you'll have to extend the tokenizer to accommodate your case.